# Arguments for and against commenting while coding versus coding first and then commenting

Tags: comments

What are some of the arguments for and against commenting code while it is being written versus coming back later to write all the comments? How about writing comments before writing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think writing comments while coding is EXTREMELY important, but that shouldn't preclude you from going back later and clarifying things.

**Writing comments while coding**

- You probably won't go back and do it later.
- You probably won't remember why you did what you did.
- It's a good idea to "cite your sources" if you had to research a technique or algorithm.

**Writing comments after coding**

- You'll be looking at the code from a fresh perspective, perhaps with more insight into which parts are not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comments write code with very descriptive names for variables, classes, methods, etc.

Prefer tests to document the intent of the code instead of comments in most situations.

Comments immediately create a 'synchroniztion with code' issue as soon as they are written.

I used to comment a lot.  Now I use comments very sparingly if at all.  If so, usually for unusual edge cases that are not clear, or code that should not be refactored for a fairly obscure reason, though it looks like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Stating the obvious before this gets deleted.

1. Forget the purpose of the chunk of code
2. Self confusion

Complex code such as loops and advanced algothyms of functions
Other developers will not be able to understand the code - include yourself later on usage
Also takes up memory, performance to when wanting to improve.. could have do

Answer (score 0):

DURING.

You comprehend every line of your code the best *while* you are writing it.